# Posting current user onto SQL database and table

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have a log in system working. I also have a form where when you select something that data or value will be sent to the SQL database and on a different page display all the sent values in a table.

How would I display the user that is send that data on the table?

here is the code that I use for the form to post across to the database.

```
<form action="add_order.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="s_table" value="$username"/>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Pepsi" /><font color="gray">PEPSI® </font>
 <font color="white">$2.39</font>       

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Diet Pepsi" /><font color="gray">DIET PEPSI®</font>
 <font color="white">$2.39 </font>      

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Pepsi Max" /><font color="gray">PEPSI MAX®</font>
 <font color="white">$2.39  </font> 

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Mountain Dew" /><font color="gray">MOUNTAIN DEW®</font>
 <font color="white">$2.39 </font>      

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Sierra Mist" /><font color="gray">SIERRA MIST®</font>
 <font color="white">$2.39 </font>      

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Mug Root Beer" /><font color="gray">MUG ROOT BEER®</font>
 <font color="white">$2.39 </font>      

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Spring Water" /><font color="gray">SPRING WATER</font>
 <font color="white">$2.79  </font> 

<p><input type="checkbox" name="s_food" value="Perrier" /><font color="gray">PERRIER®</font>
<font color="white"> $2.79</font>
```

here is my code for my log in system.

```
$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];

 //Checks if there is a login cookie

 if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))


 //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page

 { 
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  

        {

        if ($pass != $info['password']) 

            {

                        }

        else

            {

            header("Location: menu.php");



            }

        }

 }


 //if the login form is submitted 

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted



 // makes sure they filled it in

    if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {

        die('You did not fill in a required field.');

    }

    // checks it against the database



    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

    }

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());



 //Gives error if user dosen't exist

 $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

 if ($check2 == 0) {

        die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');

                }

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))     

 {

 $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);

    $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);

    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);



 //gives error if the password is wrong

    if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {

        die('Incorrect password, please try again.');

    }
 else 

 { 


 // if login is ok then we add a cookie 

     $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 

     $hour = time() + 3600; 

 setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 

 setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);  



 //then redirect them to the members area 

 header("Location: menu.php"); 

 } 

 } 

 } 

 else 

{    



 // if they are not logged in 

 ?> 

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 

 <table border="0"> 

 <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 

 <tr><td>Username:</td><td> 


 <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"> 

 </td></tr> 

 <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 

 <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50"> 

 </td></tr> 

 <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 

 </td></tr> 

 </table> 

 </form> 

 <?php 

 } 



 ?> 

 </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to take the user that I log in with and add that user to the drink that I am ordering and send that across to the SQL table and display the user and the drink they ordered.

Comment: You have to give some code to prove that you have tried something.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: User names and password do not belong in cookies. Use sessions for that. Also passwords must not be saved in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might want to take this approach,

when you authenticate the user store the user's common information in sessions. Then when you have the information for the drink you can make use of the data in the sessions.

Or if you have a table for the drinks being ordered, then I am going to assume that you enter a new record per drink order. You would use a column to store the user's `username` or even better their `user_id` (if you have one in the users table).

Then when you run a query to get the drink orders, you can `JOIN` the tables like this

`SELECT u.username, u.first_name, o.drink_name FROM users u JOIN orders o ON u.username = o.username`

So this will pull up the records of the order and also give you the information of the user who the order belonged to.

Your login script is simple and does needs some work to make it more secure, but its a great start. The problem you have is that you need to expand on how you plan to save your users' information and the drink order information, then how to make use of some type of `JOIN` to make all that data flow together.